# Windows Forms Single-File Executable

Tags: c#, .net, windows, compilation, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2019.
My question is that when compiling the project, multiple files are generated, on which the executable is dependent. Is there a way to compile them all into a single .exe file?
NOTE: I don't intend to use setup.exe: I just want a single executable that I can run from any part of my file system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What files are being generated? You get `MyApp.exe` and `MyApp.exe.config`. What else? I believe you could write your own config provider.

Comment: @Flydog57 MyApp.exe MyApp.dll MyApp.deps.json MyApp.pdb MyApp.runtimeconfig.dev.json MyApp.runtimeconfig.json

Comment: I'm guessing you are targeting. NET Core, not .NET Framework. Is that correct?

Comment: Ahh, when I compile the project, under the "Debug" folder, a "netcoreapp3.1" folder is created.

Answer (score 4):

In VisualStudio 2019 you can choose the option Publish, there you have an option to export as single file. Check this [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file) link for more details.

Comment: I don't have that option. I only have "Output Folder", "Delete existent files", "Configuration", "Output Execution Time" ("Portable").
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: you might need to change the target runtime to something other than portable. `win-x64` for windows 64bit for example.

Comment: When I tryed to edit this appears. What should I do?


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Comment: what you've commented here seems to be the publish profile. You should be able to publish the project without working much on the file. The wizzard should do everything you need for you.

Comment: Where can I open that "wizzart"?

Comment: Check the link in my answer. It explains the process.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to publish a single file Winforms (.NET 7.0) app (Release mode) in VS2022:

Right click on project node -> "Publish..." and press "Show all settings" link

[image]

Choose your target runtime, I use Win-x64 in Release mode.
Open "File Publish Options" and make sure "Produce single file" option is checked.

Close the "Show all settings" dialog and press publish.

Voila!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, I was using .Net Framework 4.7.2, and this was the only solution I found:

Just follow these steps:

1. Goto Manage NuGet Packages right clicking on your project.
2. Install Costura.Fody
3. Clean Debug folder inside the bin folder(Delete all files and
   folder).
4. Run the project.
5. Goto debug folder, then to app.publish folder, you will get a single
   exe file here

Comment: I was like "what?", but then, ok, let's give it a try. It packs everything into one exe nicely, I'm quite surprised. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me, is the one suggested in this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli

On Windows you need to navigate to the folder of the project using command prompt (an easy way to do that, is to enter the folder with File Explorer, and than typing in the address bar 'cmd'), and than typing in the command -

> dotnet publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained true

You can than find the executable at *project name*/bin/Release *or* Debug/net6.0-windows/win-x64/

The release or debug folders are determined by your current project properties.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you can go to the Publish window (Right-click project > Publish...).

Create a new Folder profile by double-clicking "Folder" twice. Then select "Complete" (or "Done"). Click "View all settings" > "File publish settings" and check "Create a single file".

This works with framework-dependant and self-contained builds.